# Loop through a large number of requests via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin that fetch user Instagram Profile info and store in database via WordPress `wp_remote_get()` function. A Corn job runs after every 24 hours that update the user's Instagram Info on daily basis. The problem is I've about 5000+ users and the script runs too long and the task never completed. Everything was working great when users quantity was under < 1000.

Which PHP settings in php.ini should I change to solve this issue? I've set `max_execution_time` to `0`. Any other setting? Any suggestions?

Comment: `The problem is I've about 5000+ users.` And what is the problem with it? Your script runs too long or what?

Comment: @u_mulder Question Updated. Yeah scripts run too long.

Comment: What is your server? Apache or Nginx ?

Comment: @SirajusSalayhin Apache

Comment: you havent mentioned your hosting details, most shared hosts ignore your mods, max execution can also be set in apache. If you have a vps / own server, check php memory limits as well. But users will prob not do this, so  you would be better to look at a workaround, how about updating the user info if being viewed for the 1st time that day? save you a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to do the folowing

- create more than one cron job which call same file
- after update the user .. mark him as updated
- do not update any user if he is marked as updated
- make the updating function as transaction (finsh all or cancel all)
- finally increase time out also good

Answer (score 0):

Hard to make a valid recommendation without knowing your specific scenario, but I would change your code in the way that it visits instagram profile only when needed as opposed to for everyone via cron job.  First, the info will be 'fresher', second, you'll avoid having the problem you're describing.

For instance, when a user visits their profile, a call is made to Instagram and data is pulled.  You store the data in your database the same way as before, only with a timestamp.  Also in the code, make sure that it doesn't pull data unless it's been 24 hours since the last refresh.  Hope this helps.